# coffeescript canvas fails to draw

Tags: canvas, coffeescript

I'm trying to translate a little piece of javascript code (see commented out block) into coffeescript, but the canvas remains empty.

Coffeescript:

```
class CanvasDrawing
    constructor: (canvasID) ->
        @canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID)
        @context = @canvas.getContext "2d"

    drawLine: ->
        y = 5/8 * @canvas.height

        @context.beginPath()
        @context.moveTo 0, @y
        @context.lineTo @canvas.width, @y
        @context.closePath()
        @context.stroke()
        pos = 
            start: 
                x: 0
                y: @y
            end: 
                x: @canvas.width
                y: @y

    window.CanvasDrawing = CanvasDrawing
```

html/javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>CanvasDrawing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="CanvasDrawing.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvasDrawing = new CanvasDrawing("canvas");
            canvasDrawing.drawLine();
        </script>

        <!--
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, 5/8 * canvas.height);
            context.lineTo(canvas.width, 5/8 * canvas.height);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        </script>
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The commented out javascript code doesn't produce pretty output, but it works in Chrome.
What am I missing?

Comment: the code after the class declaration is indented in my code. It got lost in pasting.

Comment: I've never set width/height of my canvases with css. They have proper `width` and `height` attributes. Perhaps give those a shot?

Comment: @herrturtur I fixed the indentation for you, though that may itself indicate an issue if your CoffeeScript code contains a mixture of tabs and spaces.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham I checked the source and it doesn't contain leading whitespaces. Must have snuck in while trying to fix indentation myself.

Comment: @MattGreer Tried replacing the css with the proper width and height attributes... no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign `y` as a property of the instance, so the `@y` argument passed to the drawing functions is *undefined*.

```
@y = 5/8 * @canvas.height
```

---

Unrelated: you can declare `class window.CanvasDrawing` and ditch that last line.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about class window.CanvasDrawing

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is simply that you wrote

```
timeline.drawLine();
```

when you meant

```
canvasDrawing.drawLine();
```

Comment: Sorry, just fixed that. It's not the problem. I previously had the variable named timeline and forgot to change that instance for this post.